# Functionality to a hide all posts from specific employer from results list?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

Add ability to hide all posts from a specific employer, for example there are situations you do not want to work for a particular employer, but you get 10 jobs posts from that employer alone.

This happens over and over.

Comment: You aren't replying with "not interested?"

Comment: @Robert I think this is on the job search side.

Comment: @agilecode out of curiosity, is there some specific reason why you don't want to work there that would be so overwhelming you would pass on your dream job if this company was the one offering it?  Or are you just seeing too many listings for this company?

Comment: @NickLarsen some companies have exit contracts that specifically prohibit applying for a job there again.

Comment: @djechlin: That seems short-sighted; it seems to presume that employees will stick around forever, regardless of the conditions.  Is there a legitimate reason for such a requirement?

Comment: @RobertHarvey to raise the stakes on loyalty. Whether it's a good strategic calculation I don't know, and it seems morally questionable in the same way monopolies are.

Comment: Maybe the 10 jobs posts from that employer alone need sorting to group post for a single employer together.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get where you're coming from, plus there are companies out there with not-so-great reputation that you may want to avoid. It sounds like a decent suggestion to me. I'll put it on the wishlist.

But, I tagged it as deferred. I'll certainly bring it up, but I can't promise when or if it'll get implemented.